# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () in nextJS

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS Amplify to deploy the NextJS server.

I am also using Cloudfront.
Following is my `amplify.yaml`

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    test:
      commands:
        - yarn test
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
        - yarn invalidate-cloudfront
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

After deployment if I try to access the page which was there for a while in my browser - which I haven't closed and not used for a while. It now starts to show a white blank page. It should auto-reload to fetch the new static chunks. It auto reloads but then stops and do not fetch the latest chunks only for `_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-4bf5307601fceba8.js` and `_next/static/chunks/pages/_main-4bf5307601fceba8.js`. It says
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`.
What could possibly cause this?